# Adding variables to parseTweet in streamR package

Tags: r, parsing, twitter, dataframe

I've been using the function parseTweets from streamR package for R and it works well, but when "reading" the tweets through the readTweets function, I came across some variables that are not being parsed (for example, user background color).

Upon looking at the code it seemed pretty straightforward to just add the variables that were being overlooked, however when I do this writing to the data frame seems to skip these "new" variables. I've already debugged the variables themselves and they do work. Can anyone see what i'm missing!?

```
     parseTweet_more <- function(tweets, simplify=FALSE, verbose=TRUE){

    ## from json to list
    results.list <- readTweets(tweets, verbose=FALSE)

    # if no text in list, change it to NULL
    if (length(results.list)==0){
        stop(deparse(substitute(tweets)), " did not contain any tweets. ",
            "See ?parseTweets for more details.")
    }

    # constructing data frame with tweet and user variable
    df <- data.frame(
        text = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'text'),
        screen_name = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'screen_name')),
        retweet_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('retweeted_status', 'retweet_count')),
        favorited = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'favorited'),
        truncated = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'truncated'),
        hola='de huebos',
        id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'id_str'),
        in_reply_to_screen_name = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_screen_name'),
        source = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'source'),
        retweeted = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'retweeted'),
        created_at = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'created_at'),
        in_reply_to_status_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'),
        in_reply_to_user_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str'),
        lang = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'lang'),
        listed_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'listed_count')),
        verified = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'verified')),
        location = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'location')),
        user_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'id_str')),
        description = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'description')),
        geo_enabled = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'geo_enabled')),
        user_created_at = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'created_at')),
        statuses_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'statuses_count')),
        followers_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'followers_count')),
        favourites_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'favourites_count')),
        protected = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'protected')),
        user_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'url')),
        name = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'name')),
        time_zone = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'time_zone')),
        user_lang = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'lang')),
        utc_offset = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'utc_offset')),
        following_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'friends_count')),
        is_translation_enabled = unlistWithNA(results.list,c('user','is_translation_enabled')),

        #THIS DOESN'T "WRITE" INTO DATA FRAME!
        profile_background_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_background_color')),
        profile_image_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_image_url'),
        profile_link_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_link_color')),
        profile_sidebar_border_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_sidebar_border_color')),
        profile_sidebar_fill_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_sidebar_fill_color')),
        profile_text_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','profile_text_color')), 
        following = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user','following')),
        stringsAsFactors=F)

    # retweet_count is extracted from retweeted_status. If this is not a RT, set to zero
    df$retweet_count[is.na(df$retweet_count)] <- 0

    # adding geographic variables and url entities
    if (simplify==FALSE){
        df$country_code <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'country_code'))
        df$country <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'country'))
        df$place_type <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_type'))
        df$full_name <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'full_name'))
        df$place_name <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_name'))
        df$place_id <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_id'))
        place_lat_1 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 1, 2))
        place_lat_2 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 2, 2))
        df$place_lat <- sapply(1:length(results.list), function(x) 
            mean(c(place_lat_1[x], place_lat_2[x]), na.rm=TRUE))
        place_lon_1 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 1, 1))
        place_lon_2 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 3, 1))
        df$place_lon <- sapply(1:length(results.list), function(x) 
            mean(c(place_lon_1[x], place_lon_2[x]), na.rm=TRUE))
        df$lat <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('geo', 'coordinates', 1))
        df$lon <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('geo', 'coordinates', 2))
        df$expanded_url <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('entities', 'urls', 1, 'expanded_url'))
        df$url <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('entities', 'urls', 1, 'url'))
            }

    # information message
    if (verbose==TRUE) cat(length(df$text), "tweets have been parsed.", "\n")
    return(df)
}


unlistWithNA <- function(lst, field){
    if (length(field)==1){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], '[[', field))
    }
    if (length(field)==2){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==3 & field[1]!="geo"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]]))
    }
    if (field[1]=="geo"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[as.numeric(field[3])]]))
    }

    if (length(field)==4 && field[2]!="urls"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[field[4]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[field[4]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==4 && field[2]=="urls"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[as.numeric(field[3])]][[field[4]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==6 && field[2]=="bounding_box"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) 
            x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[as.numeric(field[4])]][[as.numeric(field[5])]][[as.numeric(field[6])]]))
    }
    return(vect)
}
```

Comment: Holy minimal example, batman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, however with the following code from this location [streamR git](https://github.com/pablobarbera/streamR/blob/master/streamR-mongo/R/parseTweets.R) and `data(example_tweets)` from `streamR` package, the variables you mentioned have been parsed

**Code:**

```
#load package for sample tweets
require(streamR)
data(example_tweets)

#download code from above link and add 'profile_...' variables

parseTweets_new <- function(tweets, simplify=FALSE, verbose=TRUE){

    ## from json to list
    results.list <- readTweets(tweets, verbose=FALSE)

    # if no text in list, change it to NULL
    if (length(results.list)==0){
        stop(deparse(substitute(tweets)), " did not contain any tweets. ",
            "See ?parseTweets for more details.")
    }

    # constructing data frame with tweet and user variable
    df <- data.frame(
        text = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'text'),
        retweet_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('retweeted_status', 'retweet_count')),
        favorited = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'favorited'),
        truncated = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'truncated'),
        id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'id_str'),
        in_reply_to_screen_name = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_screen_name'),
        source = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'source'),
        retweeted = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'retweeted'),
        created_at = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'created_at'),
        in_reply_to_status_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'),
        in_reply_to_user_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str'),
        lang = unlistWithNA(results.list, 'lang'),
        listed_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'listed_count')),
        verified = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'verified')),
        location = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'location')),
        user_id_str = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'id_str')),
        description = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'description')),
        geo_enabled = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'geo_enabled')),
        user_created_at = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'created_at')),
        statuses_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'statuses_count')),
        followers_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'followers_count')),
        favourites_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'favourites_count')),
        protected = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'protected')),
        user_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'url')),
        name = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'name')),
        time_zone = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'time_zone')),
        user_lang = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'lang')),
        utc_offset = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'utc_offset')),
        friends_count = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'friends_count')),
        screen_name = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', 'screen_name')),

        #Added new variables here

        profile_background_color = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_background_color")),
        profile_background_image_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_background_image_url")),
        profile_background_image_url_https = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_background_image_url_https")),
        profile_image_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_image_url")),
        profile_image_url_https = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_image_url_https")),
        profile_banner_url = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_banner_url")),
        following = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "following")),
        follow_request_sent = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "follow_request_sent")),
        notifications = unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "notifications")),
        stringsAsFactors=F)

    # retweet_count is extracted from retweeted_status. If this is not a RT, set to zero
    df$retweet_count[is.na(df$retweet_count)] <- 0

    # adding geographic variables and url entities
    if (simplify==FALSE){
        df$country_code <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'country_code'))
        df$country <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'country'))
        df$place_type <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_type'))
        df$full_name <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'full_name'))
        df$place_name <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_name'))
        df$place_id <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'place_id'))
        place_lat_1 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 1, 2))
        place_lat_2 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 2, 2))
        df$place_lat <- sapply(1:length(results.list), function(x)
            mean(c(place_lat_1[x], place_lat_2[x]), na.rm=TRUE))
        place_lon_1 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 1, 1))
        place_lon_2 <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('place', 'bounding_box', 'coordinates', 1, 3, 1))
        df$place_lon <- sapply(1:length(results.list), function(x)
            mean(c(place_lon_1[x], place_lon_2[x]), na.rm=TRUE))
        df$lat <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('geo', 'coordinates', 1))
        df$lon <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('geo', 'coordinates', 2))
        df$expanded_url <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('entities', 'urls', 1, 'expanded_url'))
        df$url <- unlistWithNA(results.list, c('entities', 'urls', 1, 'url'))

    }

    # information message
    if (verbose==TRUE) cat(length(df$text), "tweets have been parsed.", "\n")
    return(df)
}


unlistWithNA <- function(lst, field){
    if (length(field)==1){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], '[[', field))
    }
    if (length(field)==2){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==3 & field[1]!="geo"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]]))
    }
    if (field[1]=="geo"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) !is.null(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[as.numeric(field[3])]]))
    }

    if (length(field)==4 && field[2]!="urls"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[field[4]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[field[4]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==4 && field[2]=="urls"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x) x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[as.numeric(field[3])]][[field[4]]]))
    }
    if (length(field)==6 && field[2]=="bounding_box"){
        notnulls <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) length(x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]])>0))
        vect <- rep(NA, length(lst))
        vect[notnulls] <- unlist(lapply(lst[notnulls], function(x)
            x[[field[1]]][[field[2]]][[field[3]]][[as.numeric(field[4])]][[as.numeric(field[5])]][[as.numeric(field[6])]]))
    }
    return(vect)
}

readTweets <- function(tweets, verbose=TRUE){
    ## checking input is correct
    if (is.null(tweets)){
        stop("Error: you need to specify file or object where tweets text was stored.")
    }

    ## Read the text file and save it in memory as a list
    if (length(tweets)==1 && file.exists(tweets)){
        lines <- readLines(tweets, encoding="UTF-8")
    }
    else {
        lines <- tweets
    }

    results.list <- lapply(lines[nchar(lines)>0], function(x) tryCatch(fromJSON(x), error=function(e) e))

    ## removing lines that do not contain tweets or were not properly parsed
    errors <- which(unlist(lapply(results.list, length))<18)
    if (length(errors)>0){
        results.list <- results.list[-errors]
    }

    # information message
    if (verbose==TRUE) cat(length(results.list), "tweets have been parsed.", "\n")
    return(results.list)
}
```

**Output:**

```
#Parse tweets, displaying only 2 columns for space constraints

tweets.df<-parseTweets_new(example_tweets)
#> tweets.df[,grep('profile',colnames(tweets.df))[1:2]]
#   profile_background_color                                                     profile_background_image_url
#1                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#2                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#3                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#4                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#5                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#6                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#7                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#8                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#9                    C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
#10                   C0DEED http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/656927849/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png
```

As we can see, this code works with adding new variables, what is your output for `unlistWithNA(results.list, c('user', "profile_background_color"))`.I suspect some issues with your tweets data,let us know...

Comment: Hi, I don't seem to know what was different from mine, but it works perfectly! Thanks!